# Windows Store App Assembly overrides local assembly?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I'm not quite sure how to explain this, so forgive me for the somewhat sketchy details, but here's what I observe - 
I have a windows store app, written in C#, which references a class assembly, also written in C# (.net 4.5)
I use this app on my laptop - sometimes the store version and sometimes the latest version through visual studio

I then created a completely separated project, for some other work I'm doing, and I wanted to re-use the same assembly. these are just demo projects of mine so I copied the code to a different place on my disk and included it in my second project.

Both projects worked fine.

I since changed the code of the project used by the windows store app - I added a second parameter to a public static method - and since then I get a compile time error in my second project, complaining that 'No overload of method xxxx takes 1 argument'.

I can't explain it.

Using F12 to get to the definition of the method from the line causing the error I can see the method signature and it definitely takes 1 parameter (in this version).
I used Telerik's JustDecompile on the assembly in the bin/debug folder and I can see my method taking just one parameter.

Adding a second parameter of null when calling the method allows me to build, despite the method clearly requiring only one parameter in the version within the solution.

The reference is a project reference, the path points to the right place, copy to local is set to true.

I'm not sure why the newer version of the assembly definition is used?

I even tried to uninstall the windows store application, but it did not help

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like there's something going on with the resolution pathway taken by the build. A few things to check would be:

- is the newer assembly being placed in the GAC. If so this may be causing the build to resolve to the GAC assembly (as GAC is usually earlier in the resolution pathway)
- is the hintpath in the project exactly correct (i.e. pointing to the copy that doesn't have the changes) - the best way to check this is to open the project file in a text editor and check it there
- do you have any errant references to the newer assembly (in addition to the reference to the one you expect)

Also might be worth playing with the 'use specific version' setting on the reference to try and force it to resolve to the version that doesn't have the changes

Comment: Thanks, I have checked the GAC before and the assembly was not there. at the time I also looked at the path in the references and it looked ok, but you are correct - the hint path in the csproj is different and is pointed at the other location. I don't know why. I have removed and re-added the reference (as a project reference) and still the hint path somehow goes to the other location, how come? (changing the path in notepad works...)